# OutputCacheAttribute - does it vary on HTTP method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I have a following method in my controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD")]
[OutputCache(Duration="3600" VaryByParam="None" VaryByHeader="Access-Control-Request-Headers;Origin")]
public new ActionResult Index()
{
//action body
}
```

It is handling both GET and OPTIONS (CORS) calls and so far there has been no problem. I've recently added the OutputCache attribute and started wondering if it's possible to cache a flawed OPTIONS response, by calling the GET. Namely, let's say a user with malicious intents calls my GET call with the CORS headers that I vary on. Is it possible that a user making the OPTIONS call with the same headers (this time used properly), will instead get the response from the previously cached GET, therefore nuking the whole OPTIONS call for the duration of the cache?

I was looking for an information, if the HTTP method is considered when creating an output cache entry, but just can't find it anywhere. I have tested this locally and it seemed that the GET and OPTIONS output could never get mixed up, no matter how hard I messed with the headers. Still, I would be much more relieved if I knew that what I described could really never happen.